# Keep strings with partial match

Tags: r

I would like to keep only strings in my vector which partially match to strings in another vector.

Take a look on this example:

```
> dput(cc)
c("BLANK_0", "Greg_10", "Luke_40", "Luke_10", "Mark_10", "NA_40", "BLANK_10", "Joe_15", "Jane_10", "BLANK_40", "Greg_40", "Hvserk_40", "NA_10")
```

and I would like to keep strings starting like elements from a vector below:

```
> dput(vec_all_compounds)
c("Greg", "Luke", "Mark", "Joe", "Jane", "Hvserk")
```

It means all of: `Greg_10`, `Luke_10`, `Hvserk_40`, `etc` should be kept and remain unchanged. Doable ?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest next approach indexing your vectors with `grepl()`:

```
#Code
cc[grepl(pattern = paste0(vec_all_compounds,collapse = '|'),cc)]
```

Output:

```
[1] "Greg_10"   "Luke_40"   "Luke_10"   "Mark_10"   "Joe_15"    "Jane_10"   "Greg_40"   "Hvserk_40"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `grep` with `value = TRUE` :

```
grep(paste0(vec_all_compounds, collapse = "|"), cc, value = TRUE)
#[1] "Greg_10" "Luke_40" "Luke_10" "Mark_10" "Joe_15" "Jane_10"  "Greg_40"   "Hvserk_40"
```

Same with `stringr::str_subset` :

```
stringr::str_subset(cc, paste0(vec_all_compounds, collapse = "|"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gsub` + `%in%`

```
> cc[gsub("_.*","",cc) %in% vec_all_compounds]
[1] "Greg_10"   "Luke_40"   "Luke_10"   "Mark_10"   "Joe_15"    "Jane_10"
[7] "Greg_40"   "Hvserk_40"
```